# Icone app android ficou menor do que o Padrão

Tags: android

Meu aplicativo ficou com o icone menor do que o padrão de exibição dos outros apps, o que pode estar ocorrendo para ele ter ficado menor? segue uma imagem de exibição.[image: app DipelNet selecionado de vermelho]

Comment: E ele não tem uma borda? Ele é mais alto que o CAMERA e mais largo que o ALERTA.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo sim tem uma borda transparente.

Comment: faz seu icone por aqui, fica nas medidas certas, e tira o padding https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/

Comment: Também estava com a mesma dúvida, sempre o ícone fica menor.